# Inject SSR React Components into CSR React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have quite interesting problem. I have a CSR React app. When the app is executed in browser, it makes an api call to the backed REST API. This API is returning SSR React Component. There are various reasons why this architecture exists. Rendering our SSR React Component is really expensive (so we cache it) and there is requirement to serve this SSR React Component as simple HTML page. Now when the app requests the REST API for SSR React Component I need to incorporate it back into our CSR app. I have created a working POC for this. I wonder if anybody dealt with this use case before and also I'd need some validation if my solution is/isn't completely crazy. The playground for the provided code can be found on this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/m410ovlyxj

Definitions:

- **SSR**: Server Side Rendering
- **CSR**: Client Side Rendering

**POC**:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, hydrate } from "react-dom";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import Hello from "./Hello";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const Test = () => <div>test</div>;

class TestSSR extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    hydrate(<Test />, this.el);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={(el) => {
          this.el = el;
        }}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.ssr }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const TestSSRString = renderToString(<Test />);

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {"\u2728"}</h2>
    <TestSSR ssr={TestSSRString} />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```